# Bash script subprocess locking Java app/console

Tags: java, bash

I have the following simple script (test.sh):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    tail -f /var/log/dmesg > /tmp/output.log &
    echo "THE END"
    exit 0
```

After calling this test.sh script from a java program (remotely under ssh), the java console (eclipse) stay locked. Then,
1) If I manually kill the "tail -f /var/log/dmesg > /tmp/output.log" process in the server, the console unlocks and I get the "THE END" message in the console.
2) If I remove the "tail -f /var/log/dmesg > /tmp/output.log" from the script and run the java app, no lock happens and I get the "THE END" message in the console.

Is there anyone to run tail -f in bg through test.sh, and continue with the java app flow?

Comment: Maybe a `disown` after starting the `tail`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with nohup:

```
nohup tail -f /var/log/dmesg > /tmp/output.log &
```

SSH will sometimes wait for all processes to close the tty before exiting. `nohup` will set stdin to `/dev/null` and stdout/stderr to a file, so SSH can exit immediately (flushing any buffers that may be keeping "THE END" from showing).

Answer (score 0):

There may also be some pitfalls on the Java side when it comes to running Unix system commands via Java. For example, if the standard I/O streams (stdout, stderr, stdin) of Unix-based operating systems are not being read in Java Threads, Unix system calls may unexpectedly block or even deadlock (for more detailed information on this topic please see [Java exec - execute system processes with Java ProcessBuilder and Process (part 3) (2012)](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-3).

Try the following Java sample code based on `ThreadedStreamHandler.java`, `SystemCommandExecutor.java` and `ProcessBuilderExample.java` that runs `commands.add("ssh localhost /tmp/test.sh");` (it worked for me using the latest Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers - Mac OS X version):

```
# References: 
#
# - "Java exec - execute system processes with Java ProcessBuilder and Process (part 3)" (2012), 
# http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-3
# 
# - "Running system commands in Java applications" (2012), 
# http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016
# 
# - "When Runtime.exec() won't: Navigate yourself around pitfalls related to the Runtime.exec() method" (2000),
# http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

mkdir -vp /tmp/com/devdaily/system
cd /tmp/com/devdaily/system
curl -LO http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/java-exec/ProcessBuilderExample.java
curl -LO http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/java-exec/SystemCommandExecutor.java
curl -LO http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/java-exec/ThreadedStreamHandler.java
cd ../../..

# create commands.add("ssh localhost /tmp/test.sh");
printf '%s\n' 'H' ',s|ls -l.*tmp|ssh localhost /tmp/test.sh|' 'wq' |
    ed -s com/devdaily/system/ProcessBuilderExample.java

echo '
#!/bin/bash
tail -f /private/var/log/system.log > /tmp/output.log &
echo "THE END"
exit 0
' > /tmp/test.sh

chmod +x /tmp/test.sh

javac com/devdaily/system/ProcessBuilderExample.java
java com/devdaily/system/ProcessBuilderExample


java -version
# java version "1.6.0_31"
# Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-10M3646)
# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)


# Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Mac OS X version).
# Version: Juno Service Release 2
# Build id: 20130225-0426
#
# use the following menu sequences:
# Window --> Show View --> Console
# Run --> External Tools --> External Tools Configuration... --> Program (double-click) --> New_configuration
# Location: /usr/bin/java
# Working Directory: /tmp
# Arguments: com/devdaily/system/ProcessBuilderExample
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at htis [article](http://kylecartmell.com/?p=9), it describes main mistakes while working with processes. What you have to do is to add a Steam Gobbler - consumer of input streams, so that outer progrem not to stuck while writing to output, becouse of full buffer.